# Mysqli Select query when where clause is using items from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, for e.g.

Table `card`:

```
card_id | card_name
--------------------
1       | card-1
2       | card-2
3       | card-3
```

Table `deck`:

```
deck_id | deck_name
---------------------
1       | deck-1
2       | deck-2
3       | deck-3
```

Table `deck_meta`:

```
meta_id | deck_id | card_id
----------------------------
1       | 2       | 1
2       | 2       | 3
3       | 1       | 1
4       | 1       | 2
5       | 2       | 2
```

Now I am trying to **select all cards from table `card` where `deck_id=2` in table `deck_meta`**.

So far I understood that it will require some relationship knowledge to create such `Select` query, so I read one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationship, but whatever query I made, either threw error or was not giving desired output.
Since I am unable to figure out what else to look for, I am unable to search similar question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join the `deck_meta` to the `card` table on the `card_id` column and select those rows where `deck_id = 2`.

```
SELECT *
FROM deck_meta AS dm
INNER JOIN card AS c ON dm.card_id = c.card_id
WHERE deck_id = 2;
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5aafed/1)**.

If you need only the `card_name` then replace `SELECT *` by `SELECT c.card_id, c.card_name`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both of the answers posted for this question by you and @ild. Both worked for me. I marked other one as selected answer because that was easier to understand (for me). Can you please suggest me if there is any benefit for using your method over the another answer posted? Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari Usually joins are faster than subqueries, mysql may could better optimize itself. However, maybe subqueries are easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

```
SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE `card_id` IN (SELECT `card_id` FROM `deck_meta` WHERE `deck_id`=2)
```

It should give you the rows in `card` that `card_id` belongs to rows in `deck_meta` with `deck_id`=2.